# Python. Redirect stdout to a socket

Tags: python, sockets, redirect, stdout

I run my script on computer "A". Then I connect to computer "A" from computer "B" through my script. I send my message to computer "A" and my script runs it with an `exec()` instruction.

I want to see the result of executing my message on computer "A", through a socket on computer "B".

I tried to change `sys.stdout = socket_response` but had a error: "Socket object has no attribute write()"

So, how can I redirect standard output (for `print` or `exec()`) from computer "A" to computer "B" through socket connection?

It will be some kind of 'python interpreter' into my script.

**SORRY, I CAN'T ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION WITHOUT REPUTATION**

Thanks to all!

I use a simple way, which @Torxed advised me of. Here's my pseudo-code (it's just an example, not my real script)

```
    #-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import socket
import sys

class stdout_():

    def __init__(self, sock_resp):
        self.sock_resp = sock_resp

    def write(self, mes):
        self.sock_resp.send(mes)


MY_IP = 'localhost'
MY_PORT = 31337

srv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Start server")
old_out = sys.stdout


srv.bind((MY_IP, MY_PORT))
srv.listen(0)
sock_resp, addr_resp = srv.accept()
new_out = stdout_(sock_resp)
sys.stdout = new_out
#sys.stdout = sock_resp ### sock_object has no attribute 'write'
while 1:
    try:
        a = sock_resp.recv(1024)
        exec(a)
    except socket.timeout:
        #print('server timeout!!' + '\n')
        continue
```

I connected to script with Putty and sent "print 'abc'" and then I received the answer 'abc'.

Comment: How about you write a wrapper-class which you can point your `sys.stdout`to instead which has a function called `write()` which basically just do: `self.socket.send(data)` and all is well? :)

Comment: Yes, i thought about that, but may be there is more standart way?

Comment: Also, i would probably consider using `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `exec()` because you'll be able to handle input/output from commands much more efficiently. I know of no standard way, lets hope some guru knows it :)

Comment: @Torxed that's the way I would do it. You may want to turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Yes, lets hope... But i must a little explain situation. I have a "my_script", which should work permanently. And i can't be always near. But i have a need to change variables into the script without stopping it. And i thought - that way was very simple, but i was wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [`makefile`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) function in Python's socket class:

> socket.**makefile**(mode='r', buffering=None, *, encoding=None,
> errors=None, newline=None)
>
> Return a *file object* associated with the socket. The exact returned
> type depends on the arguments given to makefile(). These arguments are
> interpreted the same way as by the built-in open() function.
>
> Closing the file object won’t close the socket unless there are no
> remaining references to the socket. The socket must be in blocking
> mode; it can have a timeout, but the file object’s internal buffer may
> end up in a inconsistent state if a timeout occurs.

You can read how to use it in Mark Lutz's book ([chapter 12, "Making Sockets Look Like Files and Streams"](https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-12/making-sockets-look-like-files)).

An example from the book (the idea is simple: make a file object from a socket with `socket.makefile` and link `sys.stdout` with it):

```
def redirectOut(port=port, host=host):
    """
    connect caller's standard output stream to a socket for GUI to listen
    start caller after listener started, else connect fails before accept
    """
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))                # caller operates in client mode
    file = sock.makefile('w')                 # file interface: text, buffered
    sys.stdout = file                         # make prints go to sock.send
    return sock                               # if caller needs to access it raw
```

Comment: @gek0n try with 0-sized buffer (for python2): `file = sock.makefile('w', 0)` or with `buffering=None` for python3: `file = sock.makefile('w', buffering=None)`

Answer (score 3):

Server side:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
from socket import socket
from time import sleep

server_sock = socket()
server_sock.bind(('', 8000))
server_sock.listen(4)

def close_process(p):
    p.stdin.close()
    p.stdout.close()

while 1:
    try:
        client, client_address = server_sock.accept()
        data = client.recv(8192)
    except:
        break
    # First, we open a handle to the external command to be run.
    process = Popen(data.decode('utf-8'), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    # Wait for the command to finish
    # (.poll() will return the exit code, None if it's still running)
    while process.poll() == None:
        sleep(0.025)
    # Then we send whatever output the command gave us back via the socket
    # Python3: sockets never convert data from byte objects to strings,
    # so we'll have to do this "manually" in case you're confused from Py2.X
    try:
        client.send(bytes(process.stdout.read(), 'UTF-8'))
    except:
        pass

    # And finally, close the stdout/stdin of the process,
    # otherwise you'll end up with "to many filehandles openened" in your OS.
    close_process(process)
    client.close()

server_sock.close()
```

This assumes Python3.

If no one else have a better way of just redirecting output to a socket from a process, this is a solution you could work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can i change variables in "my_script" from another thread?

Comment: Thread? You never sad anything about threads? You can (from the client side) send variable updates yes, but you would need `eval()` (not exec) to update runtime variables within your server-script.