# How to send the output of a long running Python script over a WebSocket?

Tags: python, websocket, subprocess, stdout

A user uploads a python file that I need to execute on my server and send back the stdout that's created over a WebSocket. The python file that's executed will run for several minutes and I need to return the stdout over a socket as they are "printed" out in real-time, not at the completion of the script.

I've tried using: [Python. Redirect stdout to a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430245/python-redirect-stdout-to-a-socket), but that's not a WebSocket and my React frontend can't connect to it successfully. (if you can solve that, that would also solve my problem)

I've also tried using `websocketd` but since I can't add `sys.stdout.flush()` after each of the users' added print statements it doesn't solve my problem.

I've also tried using subprocess's PIPE functionality but that has the same flush issue

```
async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        data = "test"
        await websocket.send(data)
        # Run subprocess to execute python file in here
        # sys.stdout => websocket.send             

start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

This is the `python` test script I am using:

```py
from time import sleep
for i in range(40):
    print(i)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: cant you create a file-like object, set `sys.stdout` to it, and override the`write` function to send the data?

Comment: @בנימיןכהן How would I go about doing that? That does sound like a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This stand-alone example will

1. Read a `python` script from a web socket
2. Write the script to the file system
3. Run the script with output buffering disabled
4. Read the script output one line at a time
5. Write each line of output to the web socket

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import subprocess

async def time(websocket, path):
    script_name = 'script.py'
    script = await websocket.recv()
    with open(script_name, 'w') as script_file:
        script_file.write(script)
    with subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-u', script_name],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          bufsize=1,
                          universal_newlines=True) as process:
        for line in process.stdout:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print(f"line = {line}")
            await websocket.send(line)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I used this `javascript` code to test the server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    let script = '\
import time\n\
for x in range(100):\n\
    print(f"x = {x}")\n\
    time.sleep(0.25)\n\
';
    console.log("sending data...");
    socket.send(script);
    console.log("done.");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data.toString());
};

socket.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

The use of `Popen` is based on an answer to this question:

[Read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate)

The `-u` option is passed to `python` to [disable output buffering](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Comment: To clarify, the issue is that the command runs a script that has many print statements and runs for several minutes so I need to send the stdout as it occurs over the socket back to the client, not after it's finished running

Comment: That is the kind of detail that needs to be added to the question. None of that is obvious from the current version of the question.

Comment: No need to apologize. Sometimes folks don't realize that a clarifying comment needs to be added to the question so that everyone gets to see it.

Comment: With the updated answer the ` for line in process.stdout:` loop doesn't execute until the long running python script is completed executing. Is there a way to get live logs?

Comment: Here's the script I'm executing to test:

from time import sleep
for i in range(40):
 print (i)
 sleep(0.1)

Comment: I modified the answer to disable `python` output buffering. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this class will serve as a wrapper for the server

```py
import sys


class ServerWrapper:
    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.__ws = ws
        sys.stdout = self

    def write(self, data):
        self.__ws.send(data)

    def close(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

you need to initialize it with your websocket.

the write function is being called every every time print is called (because we changed `sys.stdout` to our custom output.

then, after you finished executing the script, you can restore the standard output with `close`

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import subprocess
import sys


class ServerWrapper:
    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.__ws = ws
        sys.stdout = self

    def write(self, data):
        self.__ws.send(data)

    def close(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


async def time(websocket, path):
    wrapper = ServerWrapper(websocket)
    # get commands and execute them as you would normally do
    # you don't need to worry about reading output and sending it


start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Could you please show me how that would fit into my existing code

Comment: self.__ws is of type <class 'websockets.server.Serve'> and doesn't have a send function

Comment: as I said.. I never worked with this library. then how do I get the websocket object?